# OS shuts down but motherboard wont

Tags: windows-10, motherboard

When i try to restart/shutdown my PC, the OS windows 10 home version 1607, will shut down and the screens will go dark, but the motherboard (GA-Z270X-Gaming 7 (rev 1.0)) will stay active, all LED's are still on, fans spinning and the easydebug characters are showing C0, even during normal operation.

C0 apparently means bent CPU pin according to some research, but no pins are bent.

C0 just says reserved in the user manual.

appart from this issue and [USB ports (2.0, 3.0 and 3.1) disable themselves when a new device is plugged in](https://superuser.com/questions/1193382/usb-ports-2-0-3-0-and-3-1-disable-themselves-when-a-new-device-is-plugged-in) nothing else appears to be going wrong. Not sure if these 2 issues would be related, that is why i have linked it here.

any ideas as to what i can do?

EDIT: MB died, please vote to close.

Comment: Is this a new build or has the computer worked properly in the past?

Comment: The motherboard being “dead” simply means that you can't make trials so as to verify the answers.  People can continue to view and revise what information was gained until that time, however.  You can always isolate the fault and replace it.  The additional failure of the motherboard, furthermore, is possibly related by causal chain to the earlier problems you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is value in keeping this open, as you're not the only one who may have this question.

I know that there are some lights to indicate that the mother board is even hooked up to the power. There are also some interesting power/state features on certain operating systems, such as turning down processing power, hard drive speed, RAM, etc., but do not *actually* turn on the computer.

Technically speaking, anyone can program an operating system or modifications (such as malicious code) that can turn off monitor output but keep other things running in the background, like fans, etc..